# Transaction Table converting row to column with unique ID in Excel

Tags: excel, associations, rows, apriori

I have a dataset of a supermarket with two Columns

```
Customer ID | Product ID
100                5
100                6
101                6
101                7
```

I want to create a table in which I have the output as:

```
Customer ID |     Product    Product 
100                5          6
101                6          7
```

Currently I have 180,000 rows. The table is in a csv format and I am using Excel 2013. Any help in this matter would be much appreciated.

Thanks
H

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could filter your unique customer IDs, copy them to a new sheet and then use an array formula to "vlookup" all values of each ID, which has a short tutorial here:

http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/use-index-lookup-multiple-values-list

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a PivotTable with `Customer` for ROWS and `Product ID` for both COLUMNS and Sigma VALUES (Sum of).

Then, if alignment is required, select all, Copy, Paste Special, Values and Go To Special, Blanks, select a blank, Delete... with  Shift cells left.